# RegExp literal not being recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I'm trying to create a regular expression that ensures the user inputs 8 characters, including an uppercase letter, and one number.

**HTML**

```
<input type="password">
```

So far I have this

**JS**

```
var validator = '^(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9]).{8,}$'
```

What I'd like to do is this:

```
   $('input').on('blur', function() {
       if ($(this).val().match(validator)) {
           alert('Correct!')
       }
    });
```

But for some reason it won't go through. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you have is a string. You need to declare a regex literal:

```
var validator = /^(?=.*?[A-Z])(?=.*?[0-9]).{8,}$/;
```

Better performing regex will be:

```
var validator = /^(?=[^A-Z]*[A-Z])(?=\D*\d).{8,}$/;
```

Comment: What's strange is that after revising my `validator` variable I still don't get an alert response within my conditional.

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve the value of the input. I'll put up the HTML to give you a better idea.

Comment: Sorry but that is not telling me against what value this regex is being matched. Can you just put a `console.log` in your code and tell me what is the value of the input string.

Comment: Figured out why it wasn't working. I needed some type of an event to fire off the validation. I'll edit my JS and mark this as correct. Thanks for your help!